# Journey Builder Custom Activity EventDefinitionKey when running through Automation

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, custom-activity

I have a Journey whose entry source is a DataExtension used by Automation.
The eventDefinitionKey is coming as "**AutomationAud**" rather than "**DEAudience**".

The Set Schedule is set to Automation and runs on particular days.
Now I want to leverage Entry Source Data Extension data and I have implemented final payload for execute api using Event's eventDefinitionKey like below.

```
"mobile": "{{Event." + eventDefinitionKey + ".mobile}}",
"email": "{{Event." + eventDefinitionKey + ".email}}"
```

Sample Journey Path:

1. Few emails activities
2. Update DE activity(updates source DE).
3. Wait duration
4. Custom activity
5. Few more email activities

Issue:
After activating journey, The eventDefinitionKey is showing as

```
"mobile": "{{Event.AutomationAud-d16d1b0b-somekey.mobile}}",
"email": "{{Event.AutomationAud-d16d1b0b-somekey.email}}"
```

And no data is sent to custom activity.

Expected:

```
"mobile": "{{Event.DEAudience-d16d1b0b-somekey.mobile}}",
"email": "{{Event.DEAudience-d16d1b0b-somekey.email}}"
```

This is very strange and cannot replicate issue again . But for all new versions created from existing version, the same issue exists.

If I delete source DE and re-configure it, it maps correctly to DEAudience.

PFB screenshot for reference.
[image]

Inside JS:

[image]

**Any suggestions to update eventDefinitionId or eventDefinitionKey for Journey Triggers inside the same version to let customers in the same path as they were ??**

Or if it's tagged to AutomationAud, won't the data be sent to custom activity? Since custom activity is also tagged to same audience.

PFB for JB schedule screenshot if its worth

[image]

Comment: I'm encountering this as well, have you managed to find a solution ? thanks!

Comment: Yeah long route, i had to make an api callout to get backend event mappings( upon journey validation) to check for the event binding values. 
If not matching for any of the custom activities, an error will throw.
Then open and reconfigure it. Finally try again validating from JB to check for errors.

Comment: One more thing to note, this error occurs if you change any properties in your entry data-source. ex: Adding/modifying data type or columns etc