# Journey Builder Custom Activity has strange EventDefinitionKey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, custom-activity

I have a Journey whose entry source is a DataExtension used by Automation. Initial eventDefinitionKey is "DEAudience". After run about few days. I don't understand why the eventDefinitionKey becomes "AutomationAud". Can anyone let me know why I receive that strange eventDefinitionKey and what does "AutomationAud" represent.

Here is my eventDefinitionKey:

[image]

Here is my journey:
[image]

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: yeah, a known issue, please see https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/362469/28187 , try delete the entry source and add it again

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @BoHu. I have seen the article you mentioned. Because I have a lot of copying needs from the version of Journey and auto schedule it. I want to know what exactly caused the key to change to know when I have to delete then add entry source manually. I can't check the change of key every day.

Comment: I also create a new journey and adding/modifying data type or columns of Extension Data like in the post you mentioned but I also gain the same key. So I don't know the reason why the key was changed.

Comment: I guess it is really difficult to replicate the bug, not sure what exactly breaks it when you modify entry source fields/criteria. When I create a new version for the journey, if entry source schema requires updates I normally just create a new journey instead of a new version. as it doesn't work every well with DE schema update in journey.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think I will approach your way.